# Synchronize sqlite database with oracle database through Soap web service

Tags: android, web-services, soap, jdeveloper

I'm trying to create my first android application which composed of two part one developed with jdeveloper 12c and the front end with android.

I created a soap web service in order to consume it in the android part, I created an sqlite database also but i don't now how to synchronize the data in order to retrieve it..

This is how I created the web service in the jdeveloper

```
package model.Services;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import model.Entite;

@Stateless(name = "SessionEJBEntity", mappedName = "Mobile_Survey-Model-SessionEJBEntity")
@WebService(name = "SessionEJBEntityBeanService", portName = "SessionEJBEntityBeanServicePort")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class SessionEJBEntityBean implements SessionEJBEntity, SessionEJBEntityLocal {
    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionContext;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Model")
    private EntityManager em;

    public SessionEJBEntityBean() {
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    @WebMethod (operationName = "querybyrange")
    public Object queryByRange(@WebParam(name = "arg0") String jpqlStmt, @WebParam(name = "arg1") int firstResult,
                               @WebParam(name = "arg2") int maxResults) {
        Query query = em.createQuery(jpqlStmt);
        if (firstResult > 0) {
            query = query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        if (maxResults > 0) {
            query = query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @WebMethod (operationName = "presistentity")
    public Entite persistEntite(@WebParam(name = "arg0") Entite entite) {
        em.persist(entite);
        return entite;
    }

    @WebMethod (operationName = "mergenetity")
    public Entite mergeEntite(@WebParam(name = "arg0") Entite entite) {
        return em.merge(entite);
    }

    @WebMethod
    @Oneway
    public void removeEntite(@WebParam(name = "arg0") Entite entite) {
        entite = em.find(Entite.class, entite.getIdentité());
        em.remove(entite);
    }

    /** <code>select o from Entite o</code> */
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    @WebMethod (operationName = "listEntity")
    public List<Entite> getEntiteFindAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Entite.findAll", Entite.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

i got this url :
localhost:7101/Mobile_Survey-Model-webapp/SessionEJBEntityBeanService?WSDL

in the android i created a class named database

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static final String TABLE_ENTITEE= "table_entitée";

        private static final String IDENTITÉ ="identité";
        private static final String TYPE_ENT="typeentité";
        private static final String ID_SECTEUR ="idsecteur";
        private static final String LONG_ENT ="longent";
        private static final String ATT_ENT ="attent";
        private static final String DESC_ENT="descent";
        private static final String  CREATE_ENTITEE= "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_ENTITEE + " (" + IDENTITÉ
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
                + TYPE_ENT + " VARCHAR(100),"
                + ID_SECTEUR + "  VARCHAR(100)" 
                + LONG_ENT + " VARCHAR(100)"
                + ATT_ENT +  "VARCHAR(100)"
                + DESC_ENT+ "VARCHAR(300)"
                +")";


        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mobileSurvey.db";
        public Database(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        public Database(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        // Creating Tables
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_ENTITEE);
        }

        // Upgrading database

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_ENTITEE );
            // Create tables again

                    onCreate(db);
                }



    }
```

and a class for the connction

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import android.util.Log;


    public class Connexion {
        private InputStream is = null;
        private HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private HttpResponse response;
        private HttpEntity entity;
        private BufferedReader reader;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private String line;
        private String result = "";

        public Connexion(String requete,String methode, ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametres){

                try{
                if (methode.equals("get")){
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(requete);
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                }else{
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(requete);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametres));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                }

                entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                        result="[error]";
                }catch(OutOfMemoryError E){
                    Log.i("Erreur",E.toString());
                }

                try{
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                is.close();

                result = sb.toString();

                }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                        result="[error]";
                }catch(OutOfMemoryError E){
                    Log.i("Erreur",E.toString());
                }
        }


        public String getResult() {
            return result;
        }


    }
```

and a class to synchronize data

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

    public class SyncBDD {
        private static final int VERSION_BDD = 1;
        private static final String NOM_BDD = "mobileSurvey.db";
        private static final String TABLE_ENTITEE= "table_entitée";

        private SQLiteDatabase bdd;
            private Database database;

        public SyncBDD(Context context) {
            database = new Database(context, NOM_BDD, null, VERSION_BDD);
        }

        public void open() {
            bdd = database.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        public void close() {
            bdd.close();
        }

        public SQLiteDatabase getBDD() {
            return bdd;
        }

        void insert_entitée(HashMap<String, String>params){

            String selectQuery1 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ENTITEE
                    + " VALUES (NULL," + "'" + params.get("TYPE_ENT")+
                    "'" + ", " + "'"
                    + params.get("ID_SECTEUR")+ "'" + ")";
            Log.e("insert_ingredient --->", selectQuery1);
            bdd.execSQL(selectQuery1);
            Log.e("gooooooooood --->", "good");


        }
    public Cursor get_entitée() {
        String s = "";
        String selectQuery = " select * from " + TABLE_ENTITEE;

        Cursor cursor = bdd.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    }
```

but i'm blocked how to pass data through the web service... can someone help me please?